# Detecting mixed content warning in Iframes using JQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I have an iframe in which I load cross domain contents. But since I am loading them inside a https site, I get mixed content warnings in all browsers.

Is there a way using Jquery that I can detect if the content is mixed content is shown ?

I need to do this so that I can show a warning message inside the iframe about the warning.

Comment: Maybe this method will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38026278/1682761

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-stop-the-page-contains-secure-and-nonsecure-items-warning.html) will help you.Some information about stopping mixed content warnings has been provided.

Comment: No I need to detect via code, if the user has clicked load unsafe script to load the contents or if the iframe is showing a blank page