# How to detect mixed content with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `angularjs` application running on `tomcat`, and behind a `loadbalancer`

If the app is requested via the loadbalancer with `https`, the balancer still requests the application internally via `http`, of course.

Problem: I'd like to hide one tab that shows mixed content in this case (because I have to embed external pdf links which do not support https, thus I'd like to hide them).

I cannot use `$location.protocol()` because the app is behind the loadbalancer and always only gets `http`.

Question: is there a chance I could detect if the browser is actually showing `mixed content`?

Comment: But the app is running in the client web browser, that requested the page via https. Doesn't matter that internally in your network it's downloaded via http.

Comment: You didn't understand me: the webapp will contain embedded resources/links that do not support https. Therefore we have a mixed content problem, and therefore I want to detect it. I cannot detect it by protocol as behind the loadbalancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect it in the simple way. You can try to listen load event on iframe and set timeout, and when timeout triggered, block iframe because iframe didn't loaded like this ([jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/L6rj2deh/2)):

```
checkMixedContent(urlToCheck, function(urlToCheck) {
    // For example, change location
    alert('ok');
    // load iframe
}, function() {
    alert('Error: resource timed out');
    // hide iframe / show message
}, checkDelay);

function checkMixedContent(urlToCheck, successCallback, errorCallback, checkDelay, dontCheckOnError) {
    checkDelay = checkDelay || 10000;
    // 1. Create invisible iframe and append it to body
    var iframeHelper = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframeHelper.src = urlToCheck;
    iframeHelper.height = 0;
    iframeHelper.width = 0;
    iframeHelper.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(iframeHelper);

    // 2. Set time out and while content on iframeHelper.src should be definitely loaded
    var checkTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        errorCallback(urlToCheck);
    }, checkDelay);

    var onLoad = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(checkTimeout); // if OK - not show error => clearTimeout

        iframeHelper.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
        iframeHelper.removeEventListener('error', onError);
        document.body.removeChild(iframeHelper);
        successCallback(urlToCheck);
    };

    var onError = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(checkTimeout); // if OK - not show error => clearTimeout

        iframeHelper.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
        iframeHelper.removeEventListener('error', onError);
        document.body.removeChild(iframeHelper);
        errorCallback(urlToCheck);
    };

    // 3. If everything is fine - "load" should be triggered
    iframeHelper.addEventListener('load', onLoad);


    // Turn "true" in case of "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"
    if (!dontCheckOnError) {
        iframeHelper.addEventListener('error', onError);
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, I don't think this will actually work, because when you point an iframe at e.g. an HTTP URL where the iframe is inside an HTTPS web page, the onload event still fires. You get a "Mixed Content" error in the javascript console, but it still fires the iframe's onload event and it does _not_ fire the iframe's onerror event. It's basically undetectable. Here's the bug ticket in the Chromium project where it's marked as WONTFIX: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365457

Comment: @jangosteve Thanks for the info, it was long ago and I don't remember the details... But there is the example https://jsfiddle.net/L6rj2deh/2/ and it doesn't call "load". Calls error callback after time out

Comment: @jangosteve just run their example on https jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLcbL/ . They provided it on http . That ticket is about "not valid URL" in general. If we have body in "https" and iframe in "http", it doesn't call "onload".